# CMakeList.txt set up for restbed

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clion, restbed

I am fairly new to CMake and using C++ Frameworks and have trouble setting up my project. When I try to build it I get the following error

```
/Users/adjust/Documents/C++/WebService/main.cpp:7:10: fatal error: 'restbed' file not found
```

I cloned the restbed repo into my project folder WebService. The Build was no problem, in restbed.build make test succeeded to 100%.

Troubleshooting the issue did not lead to success (yet) so I hope that maybe with a solution to my answer other newbies might be helped in the future as well.

I am using CLion on OS X and my CMakeList.txt file as followed.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(WebService)

#Set Version
set (WebService_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (WebService_VERSION_MAJOR 0)

#Setup Asio
find_path( asio_INCLUDE asio.hpp HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/asio/asio/include" "/usr/include" "/usr/local/include" "/opt/local/include" )

if ( asio_INCLUDE )
    set( ASIO_FOUND TRUE )
    set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DASIO_STANDALONE=YES" )

    message( STATUS "${Green}Found ASIO include at: ${asio_INCLUDE}${Reset}" )
else ( )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "${Red}Failed to locate ASIO dependency.${Reset}" )
endif ( )
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

#Setup OpenSSl
find_library( ssl_LIBRARY ssl ssleay32 HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )
find_library( crypto_LIBRARY crypto libeay32 HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )
find_path( ssl_INCLUDE openssl/ssl.h HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/inc32" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/include" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" "/usr/include" "/usr/local/include" "/opt/local/include" )

if ( ssl_INCLUDE AND ssl_LIBRARY AND crypto_LIBRARY )
    set( OPENSSL_FOUND TRUE )
    add_definitions( -DBUILD_SSL=TRUE )

    if ( APPLE AND BUILD_SSL )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-deprecated-declarations" )
    endif( )

    message( STATUS "${Green}Found OpenSSL library at: ${ssl_LIBRARY}${Reset}" )
    message( STATUS "${Green}Found OpenSSL include at: ${ssl_INCLUDE}${Reset}" )
    message( STATUS "${Green}Found Crypto library at: ${crypto_LIBRARY}${Reset}" )
else ( )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "${Red}Failed to locate OpenSSL dependency. see restbed/dependency/openssl; ./config shared; make all${Reset}" )
endif ( )

# RestBED
set( restbed_SOURCE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/restbed" )

if ( restbed_SOURCE )
    set( restbed_FOUND TRUE )
    set( restbed_BUILD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/restbed_build" )
    set( restbed_DISTRIBUTION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/distribution" )
    set( restbed_INCLUDE "${restbed_DISTRIBUTION}/include" )
    set( restbed_LIBRARY "${restbed_DISTRIBUTION}/library" )

    message( STATUS "${Green}Found Restbed include at: ${restbed_SOURCE}${Reset}" )
else ( )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "${Red}Failed to locate Restbed dependency.${Reset}" )
endif ( )
# find all files from restbed library
file(GLOB_RECURSE restbed_LIBRARY_FILES
        "${restbed_LIBRARY}/*.a")

include_directories(${restbed_INCLUDE})


add_executable(WebService main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(WebService ${restbed_LIBRARY_FILES})
```

I understood that I need only the library and include of the distribution folder. What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT:

I found the mistake, simply make sure that you are setting the path actual directory, here is the solution:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(WebService)

#Set Version
set (WebService_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (WebService_VERSION_MAJOR 0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

#Setup Asio
find_path( asio_INCLUDE asio.hpp HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/asio/asio/include" "/usr/include" "/usr/local/include" "/opt/local/include" )

if ( asio_INCLUDE )
    set( ASIO_FOUND TRUE )
    set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DASIO_STANDALONE=YES" )

    message( STATUS "${Green}Found ASIO include at: ${asio_INCLUDE}${Reset}" )
else ( )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "${Red}Failed to locate ASIO dependency.${Reset}" )
endif ( )

#Setup OpenSSl
find_library( ssl_LIBRARY ssl ssleay32 HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )
find_library( crypto_LIBRARY crypto libeay32 HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )
find_path( ssl_INCLUDE openssl/ssl.h HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/inc32" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/include" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" "/usr/include" "/usr/local/include" "/opt/local/include" )

if ( ssl_INCLUDE AND ssl_LIBRARY AND crypto_LIBRARY )
    set( OPENSSL_FOUND TRUE )
    add_definitions( -DBUILD_SSL=TRUE )

    if ( APPLE AND BUILD_SSL )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-deprecated-declarations" )
    endif( )

    message( STATUS "${Green}Found OpenSSL library at: ${ssl_LIBRARY}${Reset}" )
    message( STATUS "${Green}Found OpenSSL include at: ${ssl_INCLUDE}${Reset}" )
    message( STATUS "${Green}Found Crypto library at: ${crypto_LIBRARY}${Reset}" )
else ( )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "${Red}Failed to locate OpenSSL dependency. see restbed/dependency/openssl; ./config shared; make all${Reset}" )
endif ( )

# RestBED
find_path( restbed_SOURCE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/restbed" )

if ( restbed_SOURCE )
    #set( restbed_FOUND TRUE )
    set( restbed_BUILD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/restbed_build" )
    set( restbed_DISTRIBUTION "${restbed_SOURCE}/distribution" )
    set( restbed_INCLUDE "${restbed_DISTRIBUTION}/include" )
    set( restbed_LIBRARY "${restbed_DISTRIBUTION}/library" )

    message( STATUS "${Green}Found Restbed include at: ${restbed_INCLUDE}${Reset}" )
else ( )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "${Red}Failed to locate Restbed dependency.${Reset}" )
endif ( )
# find all files from restbed library
file(GLOB_RECURSE restbed_LIBRARY_FILES
        "${restbed_LIBRARY}/*.a")

include_directories(${restbed_INCLUDE})


#add_executable(WebService ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(WebService main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(WebService ${restbed_LIBRARY_FILES})
```

Comment: This looks like a configuration error.

Comment: Sorry we didn't notice this question.